# GStreamer: How to use GPU on pipeline?

Tags: c++, c, gpu, cpu, gstreamer

I have a project, in C++, where I need to use GStreamer to retrieve datas from a specific communication protocol, convert it to MPEG1 and send it with UDP. So I build the pipeline (which can be written like below) and when I start my program, the CPU is around 200% (which is far too many).

```
gst-launch-1.0 appsrc is-live=1 do-timestamp=1 caps="video/x-raw,format=[imageFormat],height=[height],width=[witdh]" format=time ! \
videoconvert ! videorate ! videoscale ! \
capsfilter caps="video/x-raw,width=640,height=480" ! \
clockoverlay ! queue ! avenc_mpeg1video ! mpegtsmux ! \
udpsink host=[address] port=[port] sync=0
```

After some research, I found that some plugins use CPU and other GPU. I suspect that the problem is from the encoder `avenc_mpeg1video` but I can't find any documentation that explain which plugins use CPU or GPU.

So here is my questions :

- How can I reduce the CPU usage ?
- Do I need to change the encoder ?
- Is there a parameter that I missed which enable the capability to use GPU ?

Comment: You have `sync=0` which means to do processing as fast as possible. With this pipeline design will end up with filling up two threads always. Regardless of the elements' performance. The time it takes for processing a certain amount of data will vary though. Your benchmark is flawed.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, if I change `sync` to 1, my CPU usage will drop. But will I maintain the same latency (<1s) ? Or do my pipeline need a bigger change ?